# Identify this SOT-23-3 device marked AOS or A0S

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

It's sitting in the line feeding CMOS rechargeable battery.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The markings match with a [Broadcom/Avago HSMS-2800](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/678/AV02-0533EN%5B1%5D-1217139.pdf) Schottky diode.
[image]
[image]

[image]
(Source: [1688.com](https://detail.1688.com/offer/695817777704.html?spm=a261b.11197608.mof001.106.755d2ebc6PMXmj))

Answer (score 2):

Based on this database: https://smd.yooneed.one/, it can also be an Intersil/Renesas ISL60002CIH312Z Voltage Reference